# Yahtzee combinations

Tags: jquery

```html
<body>
 <div class="board" style="border: 2px solid black">
  <table border="1" height='200' >
     <tr>

    <th colspan="3">Upper Section</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Aces</td>
    <td>Sum of all the ones</td>
    <td class="aceScore">50</td>
   </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Twos</td>
    <td>Sum of all the twos</td>
    <td class="twoScore"></td>
   </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Threes</td>
    <td>Sum of all the threes</td>
    <td class="threeScore"></td>
   </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Fours</td>
    <td>Sum of all the fours</td>
    <td class="fourScore"></td>
   </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Fives</td>
    <td>Sum of all the fives</td>
    <td class="fiveScore"></td>

   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Sixes</td>
    <td>Sum of all the sixes</td>
    <td class="sixScore"></td>
   </tr>
    <tr>
    <td colspan ='2'>Total</td>
   
    <td class="totalScore"></td>

   </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Bonus</td>
    <td>Score 35 </td>
    <td class="bonus"></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td colspan ='2'>Upper Total</td>
   
    <td class="upperScore"></td>
   </tr>
    <tr>
    <th colspan="3">Lower Section</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>3 of a Kind</td>
    <td>SUm of all dice</td>
    <td class="three_of_kind"></td>
   </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>4 of a kind</td>
    <td>Sum of all dice</td>
    <td class="four_of_kind"></td>
   </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Full House</td>
    <td>Score 35</td>
    <td class="fullhouse"></td>
   </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>sm. straight</td>
    <td>Score 30</td>
    <td class="sm"></td>
   </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>lg. Straight</td>
    <td>score 40</td>
    <td class="lg"></td>

   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Yahtzee</td>
    <td>Score yatzee</td>
    <td class="yatzee"></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Chance</td>
    <td>sum of all dice</td>
    <td class="chance"></td>
   </tr>
    <tr>
    <td colspan ='2'>Lower Total</td>
   
    <td class="lowerScore"></td>
   </tr>
    <tr>
    <td colspan ='2'>Upper Total</td>
   
    <td class="UpperScore"></td>
   </tr>
    <tr>
    <td colspan ='2'>Combined Total</td>
   
    <td class="combinedScore"></td>
   </tr>
   <section class="dice">
    <div class="die die1"></div>
      <div class="die die2"></div>
      <div class="die die3"></div>
    <div class="die die4"></div>
    <div class="die die5"></div>
    
     
   </section>
   <button class="button">ROll</button>
   <span class="warning"></span>
 


  </table>
</div> <!--  board div -->

</body>
```

trying to figure out the best way to add up the scores for each possible combination for my yahtzee game. right now focusing on the first 6 rows which would be adding all the ones, twos... etc so it can be added to the table.

initially it works correctly, adding the scores to the the appropriate section

my issue is 1) i dont want the  scores to keep adding every time i want to reroll the dice , i need it to start over also  2)  i have it so that the dice do not change value if selected  thus i do not want that score to change. I hope that makes sense.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var die1=$('.die1');
  var die2=$('.die2');
  var die3=$('.die3');
  var die4=$('.die4');
  var die5=$('.die5');
  var turns=3;
  var dice;
  var dice_value = new Array(5);
  var ones=0;
  var twos=0;
  var threes=0;
  var fours=0;
  var fives=0;
  var sixes=0;
  
  //roll function
 function roll(die,i){
     rando = Math.floor(Math.random()*6)+1;
     
      die.html("<img  src=images/die"+rando+".png>");
       die.find('img').attr('class', rando);
       
          dice_value[i]=rando;
          console.log(dice_value);
    $('img').height(50);
 };


 $('.die').click(function(){
         $(this).toggleClass('selected');   //adds border around die if clicked
  });

 // 1-6
 // function firstsix(){
   
 //   for(i=0;i<5; i++){
 
 // }


//attaches roll funcition to each die
$('.button').click(function(){
   
      
  for(i=0; i<=turns; turns--){
       if(turns>0){
      dice =[die1,die2,die3,die4,die5];

     for(i=0; i<dice.length;i++){
          
          
        if (!dice[i].hasClass('selected')){ 
           roll(dice[i],i);

               }
         
                     
           if(dice_value[i] ==1){
                ones =ones +1;
           }
           if(dice_value[i]== 2){
            twos= twos +2;
           }
           if(dice_value[i]==3){
                    threes= threes+3;
           }
            if(dice_value[i]==4){
              fours= fours+4;
           }
             if(dice_value[i]==5){
              fives= fives +5;
           }
             if(dice_value[i]==6){
              sixes= six + 6;
           }

     
      $('.aceScore').html(ones);
      $('.twoScore').html(twos);
      $('.threeScore').html(threes);
      $('.fourScore').html(fours);
      $('.fiveScore').html(fives);
      $('.sixScore').html(sixes);
    
        
        }
         
    }
    else{
   $('.warning').html('Pick a category!');
  }

       

 }
    

  });   //button function


});
```

Comment: Didn't you ask the same question yesterday?

Comment: It seems to have been deleted, and this question is no different. You should edit your question to be a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and ask a specific question. Right now it's just a code dump with "any ideas?" which is off-topic for SO.

Comment: okay. i understand

Answer (score 0):

SO i had to create another button so that when the user is satisfied with the dice then that button would execute a calculate function.